# How to format outputs in GCP console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How to format outputs in GCP console?
For instance, I've seen a list of servers and their details being displayed in a form of a table instead of a list of servers and their details one after another.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear.

I think you can only make minimal changes to the output in Google Cloud Console (https://console.cloud.google.com).

However, if you're using Google's Cloud SDK (CLI) aka `gcloud`, you can use the `--format` flag (often in combination with `--filter` and `--flatted`) to format the output.

Here's the Google documentation for [gcloud topic formats (for table)](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats#table)